# Can you add two Google Analytics tracking codes to the same webpage?

Tags: google-analytics

I am looking to add two Google Analytics tracking codes to the same web page. Specifically one through Google Tag Manager and one hardcoded on the page. Is this possible to do with one being in GTM? I read you have to set two tracking objects, but how do I implement that if both codes aren't hardcoded on the page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a tracking code in GTM and another in page.

They will work independently as long as you don't do something strange with tacker names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to change the tracking names at all or leave as is?

Comment: You can leave it as it is.